# How can I find the questions where I posted a comment?

Tags: feature-request, comments

I posted some comments on questions, but I didn't use the star symbol to transfer those questions to my favorites.

Is it still possible to rediscover those questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your profile page there is a tab called [**activity**](https://askubuntu.com/users/85164/frank?tab=activity).

Under that, you can sort by various different things you did, one of which is [**comments**](https://askubuntu.com/users/85164/frank?tab=activity&sort=comments).